# Auto line break in tabbing

Tags: tables, line-breaking

[image]

When inserting contents into table cells, is there any simple, direct solution to make the content-line break automatically just like the paragraph showing above? i.e., I what the "cccc cc cc...." part to be at the place where the red box have shown.

e.g. "migrants" in the end of first line will auto break into "mi-" and "grants" to fit the nature width of this page.

(CODE)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

Kington Published 1 minute ago Europe is braced for three million migrants streaming out of Syria to flee a devastating new air and ground offensive by Russia and the Assad regime. Russian warships fired 26 cruise missiles yesterday from the Caspian Sea into Syria as President Assad’s ground troops launched an all-out assault on the rebels. The cruise missiles, the first to be used by Russia in a war, travelled 900 miles over Iranian and Iraqi airspace before hitting their targets in northern Syria. Both Brussels and Turkey have warned that President Putin’s deepening involvement in the four-and-a-half-year Syrian conflict will provoke a new exodus of refugees.\\

\begin{tabular}{ll}

aa & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
bb & bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccc cc cc cccc cc cc cc cc cccc ccccc ccc cccc\\

\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this question is not related to the `tabbing` environment (as mentioned in the title), but the `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have loaded tabularx but not used it:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

Kington Published 1 minute ago Europe is braced for three million migrants streaming out of Syria to flee a devastating new air and ground offensive by Russia and the Assad regime. Russian warships fired 26 cruise missiles yesterday from the Caspian Sea into Syria as President Assad’s ground troops launched an all-out assault on the rebels. The cruise missiles, the first to be used by Russia in a war, travelled 900 miles over Iranian and Iraqi airspace before hitting their targets in northern Syria. Both Brussels and Turkey have warned that President Putin’s deepening involvement in the four-and-a-half-year Syrian conflict will provoke a new exodus of refugees.\\

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX@{}}

aa & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
bb & bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccc cc cc cccc cc cc cc cc cccc ccccc ccc cccc\\

\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```